# How can I filter out some fields of a JSON?

Tags: json

I'm working on a project where I need to use my Google Maps Location History Json (via google takeout). My main problem is that I have more than a million of location objects in that json and have some fields like "activity" for example that I don't need and want to remove from all of the objects. Is there any software I can use to remove the unwanted fields from all of the objects at once or do I need to write a code of my own to do that?

a sample of a location object:

```
{
    "timestampMs" : "0000000000000",
    "latitudeE7" : 000000000,
    "longitudeE7" : 000000000,
// above is what I need, below is what's left
    "accuracy" : 15,
    "altitude" : 77,
    "verticalAccuracy" : 2,
    "activity" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "0000000000004",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "STILL",
        "confidence" : 22
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 21
      }, {
        "type" : "UNKNOWN",
        "confidence" : 21
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_RAIL_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 21
      }, {
        "type" : "ON_FOOT",
        "confidence" : 13
      }, {
        "type" : "WALKING",
        "confidence" : 13
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_ROAD_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 13
      }, {
        "type" : "ON_BICYCLE",
        "confidence" : 6
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_TWO_WHEELER_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 6
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_FOUR_WHEELER_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 6
      }, {
        "type" : "RUNNING",
        "confidence" : 5
      } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find in the end a software but code-wise it's pretty simple, read the file, convert it to JSON, make a foreach loop on the locations array and remove all of the attributes you want removed. Once done write it to a new json file.

A nodejs code solution:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var file=fs.readFileSync("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\lochist.json",{"encoding":"utf-8"});
var obj=JSON.parse(file);
obj.locations.forEach(element => {
    delete element.accuracy;
    delete element.activity;
});

fs.writeFileSync('NewJSON.json',JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log('done');
```